# Invalid project name after IntelliJ update in Java Play SBT

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I've recently updated IntelliJ to version 2018.2, and since the update, I keep getting this error when trying to start my Java Play SBT project:

```
BUILD_NUMBER not defined, setting version: 
sbt.SettingKey$$anon$4@2ad8aeb5
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
BUILD_NUMBER not defined, setting version: sbt.SettingKey$$anon$4@2ad8aeb5
[info] Set current project to [PROJECT_NAME] (in build file:/Users/username/Documents/Repos/[PROJECT_NAME]/)
[error] Not a valid project ID: [PROJECT_NAME]
[error] project [PROJECT_NAME]
[error]                      ^
```

I cannot find out why. I didn't change anything in my `build.sbt` or `plugins.sbt` files.

Comment: Does this happen for just one project?

Comment: Nope, all of them. After reading @Valerii's response, I saw that all of my Java Play projects in IntelliJ got "un-rooted" :/ Thanks anyways for trying to help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably your project structure was changed after update. Check your project modules. In my case `root` module was renamed to `project-id`. Renaming back that module to `root`(this was specified in my run configuration) solved the issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Valerii! This actually was what fixed it. Why does the `root` projects gets removed after an IntelliJ update?

Comment: I am happy that my advice helped you. I think it's bug in new version IntelliJ because module name is reseted to wrong value from time to time.

Comment: I had the same issue. Has anyone reported this to intelliJ?

Comment: @JustinKaeser thank you for reporting this issue to Jetbrains. One more note: project module renamed on each git branch switch through IntelliJ menu.